# React: How important it is to pass the event as parameter in the callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<button 
     className="delete-btn"
     onClick={(event) => props.deleteNote(event, note.id)}
>
```

The code above is for a button that when clicked, calls a function that is in another component and should pass **note.id** as its parameter.

To my understanding, when we need to pass a function with extra parameters as props, we need to pass the whole callback function as written above.

However, I tried this version of code that doesn't include the **event** as the parameter for the callback function, and it seems to still work. Is there an important difference between the code snippets?

```
<button 
     className="delete-btn"
     onClick={() => props.deleteNote(event, note.id)}
>
```

Comment: It didn't prompt `event` is not declared/defined? o.o

Comment: `event` is a global.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on whether you need to do something with the event (like getting data from it or preventing the default action) or not. This is my opinion but i like to always pass it for good measure.

Comment: That wasn't really the questipn, rather whether it's necessary to list it as an argument since it works either way with `window.event` being a global variable in the browser. Note that's in both examples it _is_ passed to `deleteNote`.

Comment: @CherryDT i see, i didn't know it was a global variable. i thought on the second example `event` was just `undefined`